# Regular Expression - 4 digits, with optional 1 or 2 decimal places

Tags: javascript, regex

Have a regular expression issue that I can't seem to quite get.

Requirements:
- Value between 0-9999
- Optionally can add either one or two decimals ( eg, 0.01 - 9999.99)

I've got a regex test and it looks to pass but when using it in my SAPUI5 app it doesn't seem to be working.

https://regex101.com/r/kB7oJ2/13

JS code:

```
var iQuantity = parseFloat(oArticle._Quantity);
var regexp = new RegExp('^([0-9]{1,4})(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$').test(iQuantity);

console.log(iQuantity);
console.log(regexp);

if (regexp === false) {
     return this.setItemToError(oInput, oArticle, 
     this.getResourceBundle().getText("regExp"));
}
```

Comment: Did you make sure your app uses JavaScript RegExes, not the PHP ones?

Comment: why not just compare it numerically with `> 0` and `< 9999.99`?

Comment: By "not working", do you mean it matches invalid inputs? You might need to double escape the backslash. Or, put the `.` inside  square brackets `[.]`.

Comment: I am just getting the result as a boolean and then doing setting an error state if false. Can't set it to <9999.99 as a value of 12.6789 could still be entered (more than two decimal palces)

Comment: You need to share you actual javascript code where the test is failing

Comment: Will update the main post.

Comment: I just tested with the regexp provided and a few floats with 2 and more dp, and it seems to be working ok. What specific value is it failing for that it should work on?

Comment: The optional one or two digits seems to be working fine. Where it is failing is the max of 4 digits (eg, 9999) It seems to be accepting 12345 or 4458980.56 etc...

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps:

```
var re = /^(([0-9]{1,4})(\.[0-9]{1,2})?)$/;
var match = re.exec(subject);
if (match != null) {
    result = match[1];
} else {
    result = "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

/^\d{1,digits_before_decimal}$|(?=^.{1,char_count_with_decimal}$)^\d{0,digits_before_decimal}.\d{0,digits_after_decimal}$/;

In your example it is

/^\d{1,4}$|(?=^.{1,7}$)^\d{0,4}.\d{0,2}$/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).